# Debugging & accessing NSDocumentsDirectory in real device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, debugging

I have my apps using `NSDocumentsDirectory` for saving the downloads & offline data on device. From debugging point of view, I was debugging as usual on simulator & was trying to access the path for these downloads & I was able to do that. I have my doubts as :

1. I am not able to access the location **`/var/mobile/Applications/SOME-HEX-CODED-PATH/Documents/`** via `terminal` that was shown in the `NSDocumentsDirectory` paths during **debugging on device**. Whereas in iOS Simulator I am able to `open` , `read/ write` at that location.
2. I am not able to browse through the **`/var/mobile`** directory as it is not listed in the finder, not even as hidden directory.

Is that directory is mounted on runtime ?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to fully understand your question. You want to access, from your laptop, the filesystem of your device?

You are not supposed to do that on a regular device at least. If you want to browse your documents directory do it through the organiser (Window/Organiser) and then "devices" tab and select your device and your app. You will be able to see your sandboxed filesystem in the bottom part and downloaded its content.

Comment: That's solved my purpose. But Still its read only, I guess, Can you confirm.?

Comment: Yes then just in terminal: chmod -R 777 [your downloaded directory]